# Show spesific sections of pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a macro that will expand certain details in a pivot table. The pivot table is grouped, where Response is the parent of AnswerOrder. The condition I want to create is that Response should only expand if AnswerOrder is not blank.

The current macro will loop through, and expand all responses, because Im unsure how I can specify that it should only expand the parent of the pivotItem and not all.

```
Sub Macro8()

Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim ps As PivotTable
Dim res As PivotField
Dim ans As PivotField

Set ps = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotSurvey")
Set res = ps.PivotFields("Response")
Set ans = ps.PivotFields("AnswerOrder")

For Each pi In ans.PivotItems
    If pi = (blank) Then
    res.ShowDetail = False
    Else
    res.ShowDetail = True
    End If
Next pi
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This `If pi = (blank) Then` is very likely not doing what you expect (or at least not on purpose but maybe on accident). This is creating a variable named `blank` of type `Variant` which is empty and compares it to `pi`.

Comment: Good catch! Changed to "(blank)". Still wont change the underlying issue though.